# How can I store sum of array in this condition

Tags: c++, sum

**problem is in inner for loop**

```
for (int i=0, j=0; i<n; i++, j++){
        if (i != j){
            cout << sum = sum + arr[j] <<endl;
            *//error: overloaded function type*
        }
    }
```

> cout << sum = sum + arr[j] <<endl;

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do? The problem is that in this loop `i` always equals `j` (both start at zero and both get incremented at the same time) so `i != j` is **never** true. So the body of the if statement will never get executed. I'm happy to fix the loop for you, but first you'll have to explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

It can be resolved by putting the expression in parentheses:

```
cout << (sum = sum + arr[j]) << endl;
```

However, this is pretty horrible style, and you should split it into two lines instead:

```
sum += arr[j];
cout << sum << endl;
```

Your future self, and anyone else who reads your code, will thank you.

Comment: If you look at the loop you'll see that the problem goes deeper than operator precedence.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but the OP seemed to be asking why this is a compiler error.  It's incredibly common for someone to title their question with the task they are trying to achieve, even when the root cause has nothing to do with the task.

Comment: Basically an xy-problem?

Comment: I guess.  More often than not, it's just a program that has been written from scratch and never compiled.  Then on first compilation something happens, the user doesn't understand, and decides their approach doesn't "work".  A question is posted on SO, containing multiple problems.  I choose to address the one that they specifically mention.  Sometimes, if I feel they made some kind of effort, I will point out the other things.

Comment: please ignore the loop. 
I will modify that. 

problem solved.
thanks again.